# How to fix 'Cannot handle this data type' while trying to convert a numpy array into an image using PIL

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, python-imaging-library

I am trying to visualize music into an image by using sounddevice to input the sound and then converting it to a numpy array. 
The array is 2D and so I convert it to 3D (otherwise I only get a single thin vertical line in the image). 
However when I use PIL to show the image it says 'Cannot handle this datatype'
The code is mentioned below:

import sounddevice as sd

from scipy.io.wavfile import write

import soundfile as sf

import numpy

from numpy import zeros, newaxis

from PIL import Image

fs = 44100  # Sample rate

seconds = 3 # Duration of recording

myrecording = sd.rec(int(seconds * fs), samplerate=fs, channels=2)

sd.wait()  # Wait until recording is finished

print(myrecording)

print(numpy.shape(myrecording))

write('output.wav', fs, myrecording)  # Save as WAV file

filename = 'output.wav'

A=myrecording[:,:,newaxis]

print(A)

im = Image.fromarray((A * 255).astype(numpy.uint8))

im.show()

I expect to get an image which shows colours corresponding to the sound being inputted in

Answer (score 0):

This depends a little bit on what you want to do.

You have two channels with n-samples (`(nsamples, 2) ndarray`); do you want each channel to be a column of the image where the color varies depending on what the value is? That is why you were getting a very narrow image when you just plot `myrecording`.

You do not really have the data to create a full 2D image, unless you reshape the time series data to be something more like a square (so it actually looks like an image), but then you sort of lose the time dependence nature that I think you are going for.

Comment: I understand what you mean, how could I reshape the data so that PIL can accept it?

Comment: It depends on what you want to do--you have two channels of 1D data so it depends on how you want to visualize this in 2D space. You could try `np.reshape()` on the array, but that might not be how you want to present the data.